# Changing the background color of a table while rending backbone.js

Tags: jquery, css, backbone.js

I have created a backbone view that renders the rows in the table row template. I wanted to be able to change the background color of the table row while rendering. That is fetch is taking time to fetch all the items from the server, So I wanted to know how I can make sure that the view has rendered completely before I call another method that changes the background of certain rows in the table. I am using just one view to render entire collection. I am using one template using handlebars.js. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Do you wish to change the color of all the rows or alternative rows or some specific row?

Comment: some specific rows based on a condition. I tried to call another method that gets all the table rows and checks for the condition and apply css to it. But it doesnt get called at all. In render methods I am using fetch to fetch the collection from server and render it to the table row's html.

Comment: Is it one view per row, or per table?

Comment: It sounds like you are rendering all your rows at once, if you are using an underscore.js template then you can execute javacsript code in there and conditionally add different classes to your rows.

Comment: yes I am rendering all rows at once. I am using handler.js template instead of underscore.js. I can only check the condition once all the rows have been rendered. I am trying to call that condition method after render but it doenst seem to update the table rows yet. It still shows 0.

Comment: @8gb What shows 0? and how are you trying to call the condition after the render? Also FYI if you are commenting to a specific person you can alert them by using the `@` and their username (the way I did in this comment.

Comment: @Jack table rows count was showing 0 as the fetch method in backbone is asynhronous. I figured out the solution by using when and then functions of jquery. Now it works like charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am just telling you how to modify the background color of an element as your question is not clear .

```
  $(" element ").css("background-color", "required-color")
```

or

```
  $(" element ").addClass("background_class")
```

and add the style like this :

```
  .background_class{
        background-color: color_name;
    }
```

If this is not what you want, try posting some code and we will try to answer.

Comment: this.collection.fetch({
                success: function() {
                    that.render();
                }
            })
In render method code is this: $('#ProductContainer').html(result));  where result has a list f rows I want to render.
Now after rendering is done, I want to call a method that gets a count of table rows and then change the bgcolor based on a condition. I know how to set the css but I want to know how to call the other method that does this condtion checking and coloring. I am able to call that method but the table row count is still 0

Comment: @8GB How is your view structured? Also You should probably edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: I tried to edit it but it doenst take it. Bear with me am still new to stack overflow.

Comment: @8GB No problem, to edit your question click the edit link right below the question. Are you using one template to render all your rows or a separate template for each?

Comment: one template to render all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments it sounds like you have a single view that's respoinsble for rendering all your rows. Assuming that you are using a single template, you can just add a conditional statement inside it. For example

```
<div id="rows-template" type="text/template">
<% _each(list, function(item) { %>
    <li <% if (item.something) { 'class="blue"' } %> ><%= item.name %></li>
<% }); %>
</div>
```

Comment: OK I see now from your comment that you aren't using underscore.js for your templates, however you should be able do something similar (I'm not so familiar with handler (did you mean handlebar?)).

Comment: handlebar.js yes and as I mentioned it is working, I cannot do anything inside the template, that condition needs to be checked in the js module. As I mentioned it is working now. Only question is it only colors alternate rows. because am using  twitter bootstrap's class 'table-bordered'. Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I used Jquery's when and then functions. I used then function to call my conditional method and I put fetch under when. It is working now and changing the bg-clor. Only problem is the table has twitter bootsraps's css "table-bordered" class so the bg-color is only shown in alternate rows.

Comment: I meant 'table-striped'  not table-bordered. It works just fine when I remove the 'table-striped' class. from the table.

Comment: I'm glad that you solved your problem out. You should mark this as your accepted answer for future visitors by clicking the check-mark to the left of this answer. In addition you probably should still edit your question so that it's more clear what the problem was.